# Instabot login issue

Tags: python, instagram

I was trying to use the latest version of instabot (https://pypi.org/project/instabot/) but I'm getting a weird error.

My code is so simple and follows the docs for the package.

[image]

```
from instabot import Bot

bot = Bot
bot.login(username="usertest", password="passs")
```

Despite that, I'm getting the following error on Jupyter:
[image]

Comment: Try :
bot = Bot() with parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

You must put the parentheses to the function e.g.

`bot = Bot()`